# Includes for ALSA not added to i.MX6 image

Tags: yocto, alsa, imx6

I want to develop an ALSA application on my i.MX6 sabre development board, but it looks like no headers (i. e. `<alsa/asoundlib.h>`) for ALSA aren´t installed in the `imx-image-full` image. I´ve checked the packages in the recipe and ALSA is included. I do not understand why the headers aren´t included.

```
alsa-lib
alsa-plugins
alsa-state
alsa-tools
alsa-topology-conf
alsa-ucm-conf
alsa-utils
imx-alsa-plugins
```

I´ve read that I need `alsa-dev` added to the recipe. Is this correct? And how can I add these headers to my image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alsa-lib` `R`provides `alsa-dev`

You just need to add `alsa-dev` to `IMAGE_INSTALL`:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " alsa-dev"
```

Before flashing your image, check your rootfs:

```
bitbake -e <your_image_name> | grep ^WORKDIR=
```

And do:

```
ls <workdir_path_from_previous_command>/rootfs/usr/include/asoundlib.h
```